# Composing dominant rational map from an irreducible scheme $X$ to an irreducible scheme $Y$ with rational map from $Y$ to $Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I am trying to understand a claim Vakil makes in passing in FOAG between 6.5.A and 6.5.B - he claims what I stated in the subject line. He defines a rational map as dominant if for some representative the image is dense. What I am getting stuck with is why, if you have $\phi: U \to Y$ and $\rho: V \to Z$, where $U,V$ are dense, you can find some dense open subset of $U$ that gets mapped to $V$. I tried to show this as a general topological fact, i.e. that pre-image of a dense open set is open and dense under a continuous map if the image of the continuous map is dense in the target space, but I did not succeed. Appreciate any hints.

Comment: A quick note: the general topological fact you tried to prove is false, i.e. the preimage of a dense set is not necessarily dense. A counterexample is the identity map $(\mathbb{R},\operatorname{Discrete})\to(\mathbb{R},\operatorname{Euc})$. The rationals are not dense in the discrete topology.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, which is why I feel like I need to use more facts here.

Comment: Now for your specific situation: I'm not entirely sure what is supposed to be a subset of what here, but it could be that you just need to observe that any open subset of $X$ is dense (since it is irreducible). Also, the preimage of an open set under a continuous map is open. Apologies if I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you! Simple enough topological fact.